# Fit JavaFX ToolBar snugly around its items

Tags: javafx, toolbar

A JavaFX toolbar always has padding space around its child items. Is there a way to control this so there's no space to the side (first item, and last item at the other edge), top, and bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the padding for the toolbar to 0px.  For instance:

```
toolbar.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0px;");
```

It is recommended you set any styles in an external stylesheet rather than in code.

Without padding:

[image: no pad]

With padding:

[image: with pad]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Girlfriend extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar(
                new Button("Open Fridge"),
                new Button("Get Beer"),
                new Button("Repeat")
        );
        toolbar.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0px;");

        stage.setScene(new Scene(toolbar));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Update for Additional Questions**

> is there a way to specifically control what padding gets placed and not? For example, I want to keep the top padding on, but get rid of the bottom one etc.

Yes, refer to the [JavaFX CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

> `-fx-padding`
>
> `<size> | <size> <size> <size> <size>`
>
> A sets of four padding values, separated by commas. For each item in the series, a single padding value means that all padding are the same; and if a set of four padding values is specified, they are used for the top, right, bottom, and left edges of the region, in that order.

The default padding for a `.tool-bar` CSS class can be found in `modena.css` in your `jfxrt.jar` from your JRE and is defined for Java 8u40 as:

```
-fx-padding: 0.416667em 0.5em 0.416667em 0.5em; /* 5 6  5 6 */
```

So, to keep the top, right and left padding, but remove the bottom padding, use a value of:

```
-fx-padding: 0.416667em 0.5em 0em 0.5em; /* 5 6  0 6 */
```

Which should probably be in a CSS style sheet, so you would really do something like:

```
toolbar.getStyleClass().add("flush-bottom"); // hmm unfortunate name.
```

Where you define the style in a custom stylesheet as:

```
.flush-bottom {
    -fx-padding: 0.416667em 0.5em 0em 0.5em; /* 5 6  0 6 */
}
```

Comment: thanks jewelsea. I knew it was something as simple as this :) but is there a way to specifically control what padding gets placed and not? For example, I want to keep the top padding on, but get rid of the bottom one etc.